# How to create a nested dict from list with blank keys across the board?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I know that the `dict.fromkeys` used as follows `rt_dict = dict.fromkeys(['name', 'description', 'model'], '')` gets me half way there, BUT, how do I adjust it to achieve my desired result of something like:
`{'name': '', 'description': {'year': '', 'make': ''}, 'model': ''}`

All keys without nested dictionaries should have blank values. All values of the nested dictionaries should be blank IF they do not have nested dictionaries.

Comment: What does your input to this look like?  Your example doesn't have make or year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what your input looks like, but this will work.

```py
input = ['name', {'description': ['year', 'make']}, 'model']
result = {}
for key in input:
    if isinstance(key, dict):
        result[next(iter(key))] = dict.fromkeys(next(iter(key.values())), '')
    else:
        result[key] = ''
```

Output:

```py
{'name': '', 'description': {'year': '', 'make': ''}, 'model': ''}
```